# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. expecting ')' , EXCEPT, or UNION , Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Am trying to build a stored procedure for single queries that I want combined into one query, Am always ending up with an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. expecting ')' , EXCEPT, or
> UNION  ,

after the table name before order and am getting the error

> Incorrect  syntax near ')'

what am I doing wrong

this is the stored procedure

```
USE [DATA_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_uploads]
AS
 (SELECT TOP 1 SyncUpdatedDate FROM [DATA_DB].[dbo].[KIPA] order by SyncUpdatedDate DESC)'kipa_uploads',

(SELECT TOP 1 l.UploadCreateDate FROM [DATA_DB].[dbo].[TDS] l ORDER BY l.UploadCreateDate DESC)'tds_uploads',

(SELECT TOP 1 l.UpdateDate FROM [DATA_DB].[dbo].[DRS] l ORDER BY l.UpdateDate DESC)'drs_uploads',

(SELECT TOP 1 l.UploadUpdatedDate FROM [DATA_DB].[dbo].[GHT] l ORDER BY l.UploadUpdatedDate DESC)'ght_uploads'
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Sometimes the error message is a diversion. Have you tried adding a `SELECT` after `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_uploads] AS`?

Comment: Assuming you intend to select one resultset, your SQL is faulty. Add keyword `SELECT` before the queries, after the `AS`

Comment: Hi @TT i want all the selects to give me diferent results on different columns

Comment: Do NOT develop the bad habit of using three part names for your tables without a VERY good reason. Here there is no good reason - your procedure exists in the DATA_DB database and the tables you want to reference are in the same database.

Comment: Hi @SMor ok I will drop that bad habit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that a comma was used to separate the individual statements in your stored procedure, however that would be a strange type of query to return 4 individual values as 4 separate result sets.

If the intention was to return the results of the 4 queries as columns in a single result set, then you are missing a `SELECT` at the start of the sub queries, this would coorelate them into a single result set:

```sql
USE [DATA_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_uploads]
AS

SELECT
 (SELECT TOP 1 SyncUpdatedDate FROM [DATA_DB].[dbo].[KIPA] order by SyncUpdatedDate DESC)'kipa_uploads',

(SELECT TOP 1 l.UploadCreateDate FROM [DATA_DB].[dbo].[TDS] l ORDER BY l.UploadCreateDate DESC)'tds_uploads',

(SELECT TOP 1 l.UpdateDate FROM [DATA_DB].[dbo].[DRS] l ORDER BY l.UpdateDate DESC)'drs_uploads',

(SELECT TOP 1 l.UploadUpdatedDate FROM [DATA_DB].[dbo].[GHT] l ORDER BY l.UploadUpdatedDate DESC)'ght_uploads'
```